# x86 port access: possible without explicit assembly?

Tags: c++, x86, inline-assembly

I have a class `IOport` looking like:

```
class IOport {
    uint16_t address;    
  public:
    IOport(uint16_t a) : address(a){};

    void outb(uint16_t val) const { asm volatile("outb %0, %1" : : "a"(val), "Nd"(address)); }

    ...
}
```

It is used to provide access to IOPorts on x86.

Just out of curiosity: Is there a way to achieve access without using assembler code manually and let the compiler generate the code accordingly?

I'm trying bare-metal x86 using gcc.

Comment: The C++ and C languages do not have facilities for I/O with "ports".  The languages have the capability for memory-mapped ports but not other types of ports.  This is why you need the specialized assembly language.

Comment: You may be able to go through the OS to write to a port, provided your OS has APIs for ports.

Comment: MSVC has some [intrinsics for port IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/outbyte?view=msvc-170), GCC hypothetically could offer similar functionality but I could not find it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yeah, it felt this way as I was unable to find anything myself and all the examples are with inline assembly usually...

Comment: Not in GCC, but there are libraries with wrapper functions, often as headers with inline functions, so you don't have to actually write them yourself.  e.g. GNU/Linux has `<sys/io.h>` providing `unsigned char inb(unsigned short port);` and so on.  (Not sure whether the header comes from glibc or the Linux kernel, but there's a man page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/outb.2.html)